# Why am I getting Syntax error when running yarn start

Tags: angular, yarnpkg

When I try to run `yarn start` I see an error in the command line that specifies that there is a syntax error.

I have tried updating both node and yarn.

````
$ node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/.bin/ng serve -H 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check
C:\Users\OMARSaid\cui-shell-ui-develop\node_modules\.bin\ng:2
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')");
          ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.```

I expect for it to run properly since there was no modification done.
````

Comment: You should give us a reproducible complete verfiable example [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Use path module from nodejs instead directly called 'dirname'

```
const path = require('path');
path.resolve(__dirname);
```

And check with your code it is showing syntax error. Please correct it hopefully it will work.